# How to access data card firmware through Linux?

Tags: linux, firmware, usb-data-card

I have a useless data card lying around. Huwaei EC 122.

I want to play around with it. See what's inside etc. However, I don't know how to access the firmware on the data card already. There are a bunch of Windows tools but I want to do it myself.

I am not looking for an exact solution...but just generally how to peek inside any device connected through usb in Linux will get me started too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the information from the manufacturer, and/or look at the Linux driver for this piece of hardware.

Comment: But how does a software called DC Unlocker do it right away?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to break it open to see the chip, read the number off it, microscope it to see if there's a JTAG interface marked on the board.  it takes a special serial cable to connect to JTAG, once it's connected, you'll be able to read nearly everything, linux has JTAG tools.